# Revive Ad can't upgrade

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I have issue with upgrading my Revive Ad server from 4.1 to 5.0. When i uploaded code and open upgrade page, i see error.
[image]

In logs i found this records:

```
    Attempting to detect an existing Openads (aka. phpAdsNew) installation...
PAN not detected
Attempting to detect an existing Openads (aka. Max Media Manager 0.1) installation...
MMM v0.1 not detected
Attempting to detect an existing Openads (aka. Max Media Manager 0.3) installation...
MMM v0.3 not detected
Attempting to detect an existing Revive Adserver installation...
schema file found: /var/www/html/etc/changes/schema_tables_core_621.xml
schema definition from cache TRUE
successfully parsed the schema
schema name: openads
schema version: 621
schema status: final
running integrity check
comparing database revive with schema /var/www/html/etc/changes/schema_tables_core_621.xml
column definition does not match: application_variable.name
table is not part of schema: banner_vast_element
table is not part of schema: data_bkt_a
table is not part of schema: data_bkt_a_var
table is not part of schema: data_bkt_c
table is not part of schema: data_bkt_m
table is not part of schema: data_bkt_r
table is not part of schema: data_bkt_vast_e
table is not part of schema: database_action
table is not part of schema: stats_vast
table is not part of schema: upgrade_action
to version: 621
timing: constructive
target database: revive
table prefix: rv_
successfully initialised DB Upgrade
verifying/creating constructive tasklist
checking field: rv_application_variable name
found field name
#! database integrity check detected problems with the database
#! 1 fields to change
```

Don't know what to do with this, i need upgrade my Revive Ad server. Please help me with that.

ps: alpine, nginx, php 7.1, mysql 5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to fix that issue. You need update your tables in database.

```
ALTER TABLE `revive`.`rv_application_variable` 
CHANGE COLUMN `name` `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ;
```